# Offline payment empty observer

Tags: magento2, payment

Im trying to do an offline payment where my customer wants to "payonbill". All works fine and i added this snippet:

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <checkmo>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Checkmo</model>
                <order_status>processing</order_status>
                <title>Check / Money order</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <group>offline</group>
                <payment_action>authorize_capture</payment_action>
            </checkmo>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

The problem however exists where i have to connect some stuff once a payment is receive for certain products. I do this with an observer on `sales_order_invoice_pay`

Thing is that the event is thrown for the offline payment however the event is empty. What can i do to resolve that? Or is there a better way to approach this scenario? At this moment i am receiving the orderId in the observer and continue from there.

```
/**
 * Execute observer
 *
 * @param Observer $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(
    Observer $observer
) {
    $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice(); ## This is empty
    $order = $invoice->getOrder();
}
```

In above example is when the offline payment is done. With an online payment all works fine.

Best,

Pim

Comment: what's the problem with *sales_order_invoice_pay* ?

Comment: As mentioned in the topic, after the offline payment is placed the event is triggered however there is no payload in the event

Comment: what you mean by no payload?? you mean you want to get order's payment method?

Comment: The event does not hold an order nor invoice. The event is completely empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by actually removing the stuff i previously did and by implementing this module:

https://github.com/dominicwatts/autoinvoice

The actual problem was that all was working fine but in the end for the offline payment the invoice is generated when booking it inside admin. Bypassing the status won't generate the invoice for you.

Answer (score 0):

Get the payment model from the order, then get the method instance from the payment:

```
    $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
    $order = $invoice->getOrder();
    $payment = $order->getPayment();
    $method = $payment->getMethodInstance();
    $methodTitle = $method->getTitle();
```

Where `$order` is an instance of `Magento\Sales\Model\Order`.

Comment: This is not the problem. As mentioned when the observer is triggered there is no eventData. The getInvoice is empty